# Cannot connect to machine via SSH after adjusting config and removing `70-persistent-net.rules`

Tags: ssh

Currently, when I try to reload SSH via `sudo service ssh force-reload`, I get `ssh.service is not active, cannot reload.`

Currently, when I try to ssh to pwnable.kr, I get:

```
ssh: connect to host pwnable.kr port 2222: Connection refused.
```

I had an issue of `Write Failed: broken pipe` when SSHing before, so I followed StackOverflow advice and changed `ServerAliveInterval` to `120`, `ServerAliveInterval 30`, `ServerAliveCountMax 5` all to no avail.

Therefore, I suspected SSH broke because of an IP conflict, because it didn't work on my Kali Linux VM but it did work on my Ubuntu.

Therefore, I followed other advice of:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules;
sudo reboot;
```

And here is where I am now. Now I've broken SSH on my Ubuntu and Kali Linux VM.

Comment: I believe my answer solved your problem with the service itself and now `systemctl status ssh.service` returns `active (running)`. The `Connection refused` issue deserves a separate question. One issue, one question. Please see [ask] and act accordingly. After you write a new question you should edit this one and only leave parts relevant to the `ssh.service is not active, cannot reload` problem.

Comment: Or maybe even "before you write a new question you should edit this one…". This way no new answer appears *here* that would try to solve the other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh.service is not active, cannot reload` means the service cannot react to your request to reload because it's not running at the moment. Confirm with

```
systemctl status ssh.service
```

To start it, invoke

```
systemctl start ssh.service
```

`service` command you used runs System V (legacy) init scripts from `/etc/init.d/`. Nowadays you should prefer `systemctl`. Instead of `service ssh force-reload` you should use

```
systemctl force-reload ssh.service
```

or equivalent

```
systemctl reload-or-try-restart ssh.service
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the `sudo service ssh force-reload` problem! However, `ssh: connect to host pwnable.kr port 2222: Connection refused.` still occuring. Will probably just install mosh instead of ssh if everything else fails